# Assign shortcuts for up, down, left, right arrow

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Is there a way for me to make Ctrl+I the equivalent of the up arrow key? Same for Ctrl+J and the left arrow, Ctrl+K and the down arrow, and Ctrl+L and the right arrow. I want to use those shortcuts instead of the arrow keys because moving my hand to press the arrow keys causes my hand to hurt.

Comment: No. Each one of `^I TAB`, `^J Linefeed`, `^L Formfeed` and `^K Vertical TAB` are already in use by Linux. See `man ascii;man stty`. While it's "possible" to wean Linux away from it's use of ASCII characters, it's a very, very complex problem.

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know that. Is there no way to change that?

Comment: Also, I don't understand the relevance of `man ascii; man stty`. Could you explain how those relate?

Comment: In a terminal window, type `man ascii`. Read the information. Type `man stty`. Read the information. That will inform you about characters.

Comment: Okay, so those just tell me the definition/meaning of `^I`, `^J`, etc.?